# SLS language rules notation

Tags: scala, specifications

I've tried to read SLS, but it has some strange BNF-like notation. Can any one clarify this notation. For example the Types chapter has the following:

```
Type                 ::= FunctionArgTypes ‘=>’ Type
                       | InfixType [ExistentialClause]
FunctionArgTypes     ::= InfixType
                       | ‘(’ [ ParamType {‘,’ ParamType } ] ‘)’
ExistentialClause    ::= ‘forSome’ ‘{’ ExistentialDcl {semi ExistentialDcl} ‘}’ 
ExistentialDcl       ::= ‘type’ TypeDcl
                       | ‘val’ ValDcl
InfixType            ::= CompoundType {id [nl] CompoundType}
CompoundType         ::= AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement]
                       | Refinement
AnnotType            ::= SimpleType {Annotation} 
SimpleType           ::= SimpleType TypeArgs
                       | SimpleType ‘#’ id | StableId
                       | Path ‘.’ ‘type’
                       | ‘(’ Types ’)’
TypeArgs             ::= ‘[’ Types ‘]’ 
Types                ::= Type {‘,’ Type}
```

Symbols like `::=` and `|` are clear to me, but what the difference between `[]` and `{}`. Also i couldn't find description for things like `id`, `[nl]`, `Refinment`, `Type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the notation used in SLS is called [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) - Extended Backus–Naur Form. It was developed by Niklaus Wirth, the creator of Pascal, and if i'm not mistaken, he was a supervisor of prof. Odersky in his Ph. D research. All Scala syntax is described in the end of SLS (page 159), there you can find `Type`, `Refinment`, `nl` and other things used in Scala.

As for EBNF it self, here the complete table of it's syntax:

```
Usage            Notation
definition       =
concatenation    ,
termination      ;
alternation      |
option           [ ... ]
repetition       { ... }
grouping         ( ... )
terminal string  " ... "
terminal string  ' ... '
comment          (* ... *)
special sequence ? ... ?
exception        -
```

The notation in SLS is slightly modified, i.e `::=` is used instead of a simple `=` and space used for concatenation instead of `,`